# How do I attach a data frame to a function's local environment?

Tags: r

**Q:** In `R`, how do I pass a data frame as an argument to a function and attach that data frame to the function's local environment?

Here's a toy example:

```r
dat <- data.frame(a = "text1", b = "text2")

fn <- function(df, first, last) {
    ## how do I set up the environment here?
    paste(first, last, sep = " ")
}

fn(df = dat, first = a, last = b) # should return "text1 text2"
```

That is, inside the function, I'd like to be able to refer directly to the arguments `first` and `last`, which themselves refer to named columns in the data frame `dat`, which I've passed to the function as argument `df`.

The answer to this question might be embarrassingly simple (apologies if so), but `R` environments make my head explode.

(To clarify: I'm aware of `attach` and all the horrors it entails; I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate the local environment but am not sure what the appropriate verb is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating the local environment and passing arguments as symbols rather than character values makes things very messy when implementing the function. Having the freedom to change environments and use function like `with()` are nice when working interactively, but when you think about writing a function, it's usually not as important to have that level of flexibility since the function (in theory) won't change that often. So here are some ways to implement the function. The first suggestions use characters

```
fn1<- function(df, first, last) {
    first = df[[first]]
    last = df[[last]]
    paste(first, last, sep = " ")
}
fn1(df = dat, first = "a", last = "b")

fn2<- function(df, first, last) {
   evalq({
    paste(first, last, sep = " ")
   }, list2env(list(first=df[[first]], last=df[[last]])))
}
fn2(df = dat, first = "a", last = "b")
```

and then if you want to pass symbols

```
fn3<- function(df, first, last) {
    first = df[[deparse(substitute(first))]]
    last = df[[deparse(substitute(last))]]
    paste(first, last, sep = " ")
}
fn3(df = dat, first = a, last = b)

fn4<- function(df, first, last) {
   first <- substitute(first)
   last <- substitute(last)
   eval(bquote({
    paste(.(first), .(last), sep = " ")
   }),df)
}
fn4(df = dat, first = a, last = b)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful (`fn3` seems the cleanest when passing in symbols).  Still wrapping my head around R's environments, so I apologize if my terminology was not quite correct.

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend doing this instead:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = "text1", b = "text2", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

fn <- function(df, first, last) {
  paste(df[, c(first, last)], collapse = " ")
}
fn(df = dat, first = "a", last = "b")
```

It will spare you many hard-to-find bugs in the long run.

TL;DR: Never use `attach`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that option.  However, for this question, I'm more interested in how to manipulate the local environment; the call to `paste` is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: `attach` attaches the data.frame to the search path (which apparently you'd like to do). I'm not sure why you talk about environments in this context.